# angular ui tree limit max depth

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I want to limit max depth of angular UI tree
i added `data-max-depth="2"` to `ui-tree`

```
    <div ui-tree id="tree-root" data-max-depth="2">
        <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="data" >
            <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

It works for single nodes. but problem is when I take a parent node with some child and drag it under another parent node. it let me to drop it. so in this case i can have 3 level. it's a visible bug.

am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

the problem belongs to version 2.9.0, i got it from npm, look like the npm version is not latest one, i got the latest from bower and the problem solved